# Laravel Deployment on Shared Hosting

Tags: php, laravel, cpanel

I'm trying to deploy my laravel project on shared hosting Cpanel, I divide my laravel project into 2 folders (i do this so the user can't check out my .env file):

1. laravel (all laravel files except public)
2. public (I moved all the contents of the file to public_html)

I put both of them to public_html, and I wonder what I have to do with htaccess file to point it to the public folder?

My htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ public/ [L]
</IfModule>
```

Btw, someone told me not to change the structure of the PHP file

Answer (score 0):

You need to Edit the `index.php and .htaccess` file in your public folder.

Why you need this changes because of now your files are outside of `Laravel` Project folder and for mapping the project you need to give a new path to this files.

You only need to change code in your `public/index.php`

```
<?php
define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register The Auto Loader
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Composer provides a convenient, automatically generated class loader for
| our application. We just need to utilize it! We'll simply require it
| into the script here so that we don't have to worry about manual
| loading any of our classes later on. It feels great to relax.
|
*/
require __DIR__.'/../laravel/vendor/autoload.php';
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Turn On The Lights
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| We need to illuminate PHP development, so let us turn on the lights.
| This bootstraps the framework and gets it ready for use, then it
| will load up this application so that we can run it and send
| the responses back to the browser and delight our users.
|
*/
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../laravel/bootstrap/app.php';
$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);
$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

And in your `.htaccess` file you need to add this lines of code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule (.+) /public/$1 [L]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ /public/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: The public folder you mean is public_html?

Comment: i did what you said, but now the problem is I got error: Internal Server Error

Comment: public folder is your laravel extracted public folder inside public_html folder

Comment: I see, now as you can see on my htaccess file, am I have to change something on RewriteCond or in the RewriteRule?

Comment: Update the .htaccess file with full code

Comment: I did, I didn't change it too much

Answer (score 0):

How to deploy a Laravel project?

1. Copy all the contents of the `/your_laravel_project/public/` in `public_html`
2. Copy the other files and folders from `/your_laravel_project` to a directory which is before `public_html`, let's call it `/core`
3. in `public_html`, edit the routes in `index.php` file.

I'm not sure about the older versions but in Laravel 8.x and 9.x you only need to edit 3 lines in `index.php` file:

1. `if (file_exists($maintenance = __DIR__.'/../storage/framework/maintenance.php')) {...` to `if (file_exists($maintenance = __DIR__.'/../core/storage/framework/maintenance.php')) {`
2. `require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';` to `require __DIR__.'/../core/vendor/autoload.php';`
3. `$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';` must change to `$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../core/bootstrap/app.php';`

Comment: I didn't need to edit my htaccess file?

Comment: I did all of it but it still not working

Comment: @Oka in the above solution you need to modify .htaccess file, in my solution no!
both of the answers given to your problem are correct, if it ain't working for you, you're probably missing something

Comment: @Oka what is the error now?